# 1994 Mazda 323 turns over vigorously but won't start

Tags: starting, mazda

I recently had my car's fuel pump and battery replaced when I was experiencing very similar symptoms. Car turns over strongly but does not start. I'm wondering if this could be due to poorly done work on the fuel pump, or if there could be an unrelated cause this time. I've tried hooking up a battery pack to eliminate the battery as a possible cause, and it still doesn't start.

I'm thinking it could be related to spark plugs, but they are only around 30K km old. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to check the fuel pressure at the injector rail. I don't know for sure, but would assume the pressure should be around 38-43psi. If you don't have any pressure there (or say you get 5psi), then your pump probably went bad. This happens for time-to-time, especially if an aftermarket pump was put in place. I put an aftermarket one in my Camaro which worked just fine ... came back two weeks later and nothing. Was able to get it replaced under warranty, but it's a PITB taking a stupid fuel tank out, lol!

Comment: I tried starting it this morning after leaving it for a couple of days. It's much drier today and it did start, though roughly, but there were two other symptoms: white smoke from the tailpipe and a knocking sound in the engine, but it drove normally. Not sure what to do now. I'm going to check for moisture in the distributor cap.

Comment: It did run well after the engine was warmed up? Did the noise go away after it was warmed up? And by white smoke ... was it continuous? Did it have a smell to it?

Comment: It ran normally after warm up, but the light tapping sound was continuous. I pulled each spark plug  wire to see what effect that would have, and replacing them all made the sound go away, so one of them was probably just a little loose. The white smoke was continuous, not particularly smelly, thought the car always belches a fuel smell. I ended up dumping a can of Seafoam in the gas tank, half a can in the crank case and another half or a little less up the vacuum tube and all symptoms went away including the smoke after half an hour or so. I believe that would have helped with moisture.

Comment: I'll be doing an oil change in the next couple of days.

Comment: Yes, don't run the Seafoam too long in the crankcase. General thought is no more than a 100 miles.

Comment: Updates on this issue? Were you able to fix it? If so, we'd love to hear about it!

Comment: Only what I described above.. problem went away after leaving it a couple of days and using seafoam, might have been a moisture issue. Hasn't happened since.